# The pdf font exported by the puppeter is different in different environments

Tags: node.js, linux, google-chrome, window, puppeteer

I am using puppeteer for pdf export. I found a problem. In the window environment, the exported pdf Chinese font is normal, but in the Linux environment, the Chinese font will be thicker.

My window environment:

> **puppeteer: "1.18.1"**
>
> **Chromium : "77.0.3835.0"**

My linux environment：

> **puppeteer: "1.18.1"**
>
> **Chromium : "77.0.3835.0"**
>
> **CentOS Linux release 7.4.1708**

Here is my node.js code

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.goto('url here',{waitUntil: 'networkidle0'});
  await page.pdf({path: 'example.pdf',width:'910px',height:'512px',printBackground: true});
  await browser.close();
})();
```

I set a font to bold

```
font-weight: bold; font-family:SimSun;
```

This is a screenshot of the browser:[image: browser screenshot]

This is a screenshot of the window export pdf:[image: window pdf screenshot]

This is a screenshot of the linux export pdf:[image: linux pdf screenshot]

Compare the screenshots of linux and window, the bold font of linux is obviously thicker.

I have confirmed that the font packages under linux and window are consistent.

I have tried some methods, but I can't solve this problem. I hope someone can give me some advice.

Comment: This is a general problem and not only specific to puppeteer. I am facing the same issue with the `html-pdf`package. There the font also depends on the operating system on which nodejs runs.

Comment: @SimonThiel Thank for your tips. By the way,do you have other `html-pdf`plugin recommendations? In addition to`wkhtmltopdf`, because it does not parse `svg` tags very well.